# For what $n$ does $\left\lvert\frac{p^nx-1}{p+1}\right\rvert_p=1$, given $\lvert x\rvert_p=1$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, p-adic-number-theory

> For what $n$ does  $\left\lvert\dfrac{p^n\cdot x-1}{p+1}\right\rvert_p=1$, given $\lvert x\rvert_p=1$?

Where $\lvert x\rvert_p$ is inverse of the highest power of $p$ that divides $x$ (i.e. the p-adic absolute value)

---

My (wrong) attempt, I have now deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $n>0$.
Recall that $|a\pm b|_p=\max\{|a|_p,|b|_p\}$ if $|a|_p\ne|b|_p$.
Then as $|p^nx|_p=p^{-n}$, we have
$$\left|\frac{p^nx-1}{p+1}\right|_p =\frac{|p^nx-1|_p}{|p+1|_p}=\frac{\max\{p^{-n},1\}}{\max\{p^{-1},1\}}=1.$$
For $n<0$, we arrive at 
$$\left|\frac{p^nx-1}{p+1}\right|_p =\frac{\max\{p^{-n},1\}}{\max\{p^{-1},1\}}=p^{-n}$$
instead, so this is not a solution.

For $n=0$, the answer depends on $|x-1|_p$, i.e.,  whether $x\equiv 1\pmod p$.

Comment: Thank-you very much. Should that $<_p$ in the first line be a $\rvert_p$?  If not, what does it mean?

Comment: P.S. So I made a mistake in my question too (now deleted).